# Console.log - getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to learn HTML5 "DnD".

I have a table wich is created with HTML from PHP.

```
echo "<li class='elements' id='".$row['id']."' draggable='true'>".$row['element_nr']."</li>";
```

Now i'd like to fetch this text with javascript.

```
element = document.getElementsByClassName('elements');
```

Then just for fun i'd like to console that variable to se what's in it. So i use:

```
var element = document.getElementsByClassName('elements');
console.log(element);
```

Now when i check my console, i see nothing. When i drag the text i see nothing. I have also tryed "prompt(element);"

How can i see what´s in "var element"?
This is my code.(Not really working yet)

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
function doFirst(){
    element = document.getElementsByClassName('elements');
    element.addEventListener('dragstart', startDrag, false);
    drop_element = document.getElementById('drop_element');
    drop_element.addEventListener('dragenter', function(e){e.preventDefault();}, false);
    drop_element.addEventListener('dragover', function(e){e.preventDefault();}, false);
    drop_element.addEventListener('drop', dropped, false);
}
function startDrag(e){
    var element = document.getElementsByClassName('elements');
    console.log(element);
    e.dataTransfer.setData('Text', element);
}
function dropped(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    drop_element.innerHTML = e.dataTranfer.getData('Text');
}

window.addEventListener('Load', doFirst, false);
});
```

**HTML**

```
<section id="drag_element">
  <ul>
    <?php echo "<li class='elements' id='".$row['id']."' draggable='true'>".$row['element_nr']."</li>";?>
  </ul>

<section id="drop_element">
  drop here
</section>
```

Comment: You're using `jQuery`. Why are you using `getElementsByClassName` too, among all the other vanilla JS going on? Sticking to one or the other would be preferable.

Comment: `addEventLister` can be added only for single element. `document.getElementsByClassName` returns collection of elements - if you want to add event you should iterate over them and add listener for each of it

Comment: It seems like, i don't really know what im doing here. I need to pratice more.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that `doFirst()` is never invoked because the vent listener you attached is incorrect.

Additionally, `element.addEventListener` isn't going to work because it's actually a live array of elements.

Try this

```
jQuery(function(){

  function doFirst(){
    jQuery('.elements').on('dragstart', startDrag);
    jQuery('#drop_element').on('dragenter dragover', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });
    jQuery('#drop_element').on('drop', dropped);
}

function startDrag(e){
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('elements');
    console.log(elements);
    e.dataTransfer.setData('Text', element);
}
function dropped(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery('#drop_element').html(e.dataTranfer.getData('Text'));
}

jQuery('window').on('load', doFirst);
});
```

Comment: Just a copy of this JS won't work for me. I will need more pratice i guess.